# How to sanitize query to accept table name as parameter PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code which works, however, now i'm just wondering if this will be secure, and not sql injectable etc.

I cannot take the approach of whitelisting table names as for my web application, more tables will be generated randomly in the future and will be passed through a URL parameter of `table`, so therefore I will never know all of the tables.

I use the first query to determine if the table which is passed through the URL parameter actually exists, otherwise I will be exiting the script which i'm yet to add.

```
$db = "database1";
$table = $_GET['table'];
$stmt = $auth_table->runQuery("Select table_name, table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_schema = :db and table_name = :tablename");
$stmt->execute(array(":db"=>$db,":tablename"=>$table));
$tableRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$table_schema = $tableRow['table_schema'].".".$tableRow['table_name'];

$stmt = $auth_table->runQuery("Select * from ".$table_schema."");
$stmt->execute();
$testing=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($testing['level']);
exit();
```

Comment: Grab an array with the output of `SHOW TABLES FROM database1 `. There is your white list ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whitelist your existing tables

```
$db = "database1";
$table = $_GET['table'];

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1', $user, $pass);
$tableSql = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $db;       
$tableRes = $dbh->query($tableSQL); 
$tableArr  = $tableRes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$whitelist = $tableArr[0]['Tables_in_database1']; 
if(!in_array($table, $whitelist)){
    exit(); //Or RickRoll Them
}
```

Comment: I get `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean`

Comment: My mistake ... query need your connection if you don't already have one:   `$tableRes = $dbh->query($tableSQL);` ... updated answer.

Comment: Yeah I already added my connection however now I get `Array ( )` when I check to see if it prints the tables in the array, so it's empty.

Comment: Try it without the database name in the query, Just: `SHOW TABLES`

Comment: Make sure that the connection user has permissions for the `SHOW TABLES` command as well

Comment: I figured it was because I never actually executed the query so I achieved this by doing `$tableRes->execute();`. Now, the only thing is that when I actually put one of the tables name in the URL parameter it still runs `exit();`

Comment: This is the outputted array: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Tables_in_database1] => table1
        )

)

Comment: Fixed with `$tableArr  = $tableRes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` instead of `$tableArr  = $tableRes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` Thanks for your help!